# Did the Basilisk attack anyone else in the 1940s?

Tags: harry-potter, basilisk

According to Riddle, the Basilisk attacked several students when the Chamber of Secrets was opened for the first time.

> *In my fifth year, the Chamber was opened and the monster attacked **several students**, finally killing one. I caught the person who'd opened the Chamber and he was expelled.
>
>   <sub>(Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 13, The Very Secret Diary)</sub>*.

Re-reading this came as a surprise to me as I'd always thought that Moaning Myrtle was the first and only victim. Yet Riddle says quite clearly that there were several attacks.

We know that large parts of Riddle's story in the diary are purposefully misleading at best and pure fiction at worst. His account isn't trustworthy. But is this nugget?

**Was Riddle lying when he said that there were several attacks or was Myrtle the only victim?**

I'm only interested in book answers relating to the first time the Chamber was opened (in the 1940s) please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Riddle's memory that Harry witnessed does agree there were multiple attacks:

> ‘The thing is, Tom,’ he sighed, ‘special arrangements might have been
> made for you, but in the current circumstances ...’
>
> ‘You mean all
> these attacks, sir?’ said Riddle, and Harry’s heart leapt, and he
> moved closer, scared of missing anything.
>
> ‘Precisely,’ said the
> Headmaster. ‘My dear boy, you must see how foolish it would be of me
> to allow you to remain at the castle when term ends. Particularly in
> the light of the recent tragedy ... the death of that poor little girl
> ... You will be safer by far at your orphanage. As a matter of fact,
> the Ministry of Magic is even now talking about closing the school. We
> are no nearer locating the – er – source of all this unpleasantness
> ...’
>
> Riddle’s eyes had widened. ‘Sir – if the person was caught ... If
> it all stopped ...’ ‘What do you mean?’ said Dippet, with a squeak in
> his voice, sitting up in his chair. ‘Riddle, do you mean you know
> something about these attacks?’

Dippet agrees that it's multiple attacks, and Myrtle's death pushed the Ministry over to edge to close Hogwarts, something Voldemort would hate to happen, as above all else, he loves the school as it's his first home.

Comment: Before we debate riddle changing the memory, remember slughorns memory he altered, he did a botched job of it, but thats because it was a difficult thing to do, and Slughorn is no slouch at magic, so while Voldemort is superior most likely creating an entire conversation that may or may not have ever happened at all seems pushing it imo. Especially since the point of the memory is to show it was hagrid at fault, which it did, while adding extra attacks for no reason would be pointless as a single death would be enough.

Comment: So are we to presume that the other attacks were non-fatal (ie petrification)? I think Myrtle is the only reported death, right?

Comment: @TheDarkLord id believe thats a safe assumption, book 2 sheds no more lite on other deaths. -edited

Comment: @Himarm - Also, all other references to the school's safety mention that there has only been a single death in decades (that death later being discovered to by Myrtle's).  All other attacks must have resulted in petrification.

Comment: Pretty poor track record for a monster that can kill on sight really, isn't it...?

Comment: I remember the quote but I have a hard time reconciling the actual implications. If indeed there were more attacks then one would presume she was the only death since none other mentioned and the context of the quote. But the petrified state is still pretty serious and nothing is mentioned of them. Is it possible also that Riddle either misspoke (made it plural) or altered it (as suggested)? Of course Dippet suggests that there was more than one attack but it seems odd that nothing is said of the other victims with such a serious thing. Maybe I'm analysing it (and possibly expecting) too much?

Comment: @Pryftan the trick with rowling is, if theres back story that doesnt make sense, thats because shes a horrible world builder, so unless/until pottermore adds additional info, were left to assume she simple wrote it as it is, ment it as it was written, and despite flaws simple expects you to ignore such flaws, as they are not the point of this story, which is, 100% about Harry potter, and side details be damned. The problem with reading childrens books, when you've experienced the fullness and variety of true fantasy, or are just a functional adult that understands her storys dont make sense.

Comment: @Himarm Well you do make a very good point, yes. Or the - other - old argument (to use the words of Voldemort) - she's bad at 'maths'; Voldemort is 'bad at love' and 'she's bad at maths'. But there's another way of looking at it I suppose: we're expecting too much; after all we're all human and this type of thing would detract from the story (as you say). That or the fact Tolkien's world was so much more complete and that's my real joy? Either way I agree with you on all counts and it's probably the only realistic way of looking at it too.